# Работа с jQuery после установки через npm

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

Создал проект, скачал `jQuery` так: `npm install jquery --save-dev`. После этого вывелось сообщение, что все ок. В этой же директории создал `html`-файл.

Никак не могу понять как в этом файле я могу подключить `jQuery` ? Что указывать в `<script src="jquery"></script>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установленные через npm пакеты падают в папку **node_modules**.

Однако, указывать путь к jQuery, лежащему в node_modules - это bad practice, потому что в этом случае вам придётся сохранять эту папку в проекте.

Копировать библиотеку из node_modules в нужное место - тоже bad practice, так как в случае обновления библиотеки, вам придётся руками её заново копировать.

Так как npm тянет кучу зависимостей (в отличии от bower), то со временем папка увеличивается в размерах и приводит к различного рода [казусам](https://habrahabr.ru/post/307822/).

Как правило, в проекте используются т.н. module loaders (или module bundlers), например [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

Module loaders позволяют подключать нужные скрипты и собирать bundle, таким образом в конечный проект попадут нужные библиотеки без необходимости сохранять ненужные директории (например, node_modules).

Самым простым из перечисленных, на мой взгляд является browserify. К тому же он используется нодовский стиль подключения - `require('myAwesomeLibrary')`.

Comment: Понятно. Но почему на офф сайте первым делом указан именно способ установки через `npm` ?

Comment: @faoxis менеджер пакетов предоставляет много удобств. Вы можете установить нужную версию пакета, указав её явно, можете выполнять обновления. Кроме того, опции [--save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-difference-between-save-and-save-dev) и [--save-dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-difference-between-save-and-save-dev) несут большой смысл, особенно, когда над проектом начинают трудиться несколько человек или ваш готовый продукт попадает, например, на github. Всё это и многое другое облегчает развёртывание, работу на проектом, его развитие.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но вы же сами сказали, что нет некостыльного способа использовать jQuery с установкой npm. Или чего-то не понял ?

Comment: В npm множество пакетов, - это универсальная система **установки**, с последующим возможным контролем, обновлением, поиском и т.д. Многие из них это server-side (например, http-server), - они подключаются иначе. Другие, как jQuery, подключаются как, например, описано выше. Поэтому это не костыльный способ, а вполне стандартный. Как Вы будете подключать установленное к проекту остаётся за Вами.